# How to preload images and then change div contents once the imaged are done loading

Tags: javascript, image, preload

I am trying to preload a bunch of images, and then once they are FULLY loaded, change the contents of a div, here is my code so far, but it just throws my browser into an infinite loop. Any help would be great. Thanks!

```
    var mydir ='slideshow_pics/';
var myArray = new Array();
myArray[0] = mydir+'0.jpg';
myArray[1] = mydir+'1.jpg';
myArray[2] = mydir+'2.jpg';
myArray[3] = mydir+'3.jpg';
myArray[4] = mydir+'4.jpg';
myArray[5] = mydir+'5.jpg';
myArray[6] = mydir+'6.jpg';
myArray[7] = mydir+'7.jpg';

var myWidth = new Array();
myWidth[0] = '470';
myWidth[1] = '450';
myWidth[2] = '450';
myWidth[3] = '500';
myWidth[4] = '550';
myWidth[5] = '450';
myWidth[6] = '800';
myWidth[7] = '300';

var myCheck = new Array();

function preloader(images){
         var i = 0;

         // start preloading
         for(i=0; i<=images.length; i++){
            imageObj = new Image();
            imageObj.src=images[i];
            imageObj.onLoad = check(i, images.length);
         };

    }


function checkimg(data, w) {
        p=0;
        z=0;
        o = 'no';
        var myImg = new Image();
        myImg.src = data;

        while (p == 0) {

            if (myImg.naturalWidth == w) {
            p = 1;
            o = 'yes';
            }
        z++;
        }
return o;

}


function check(e,i) {


        if( e == i ){

             if (document.getElementById('myss') != null) {

    //now we need to make sure each image is fully loaded
    for(i=0; i<=myArray.length; i++){

        p=0;
        z=0;

        myCheck[i] = checkimg(myArray[i], myWidth[i]);


    }//end foreach

    if (myCheck.join('') == 'yesyesyesyesyesyesyesyes') {

    document.getElementById('myss').innerHTML = '<embed src="RectangleSlideshow.swf" width="1028px" height="324px"></embed>';

        }
    }

        };
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need a sort of image pre-loading for a gallery.
I have that code implemented in my index web page:

http://www.becomingthebeast.com/index.html

See if it works for you.

Comment: I was able to use your code and i no longer have the infinte loop, but it still doesn't have the images fully loaded

Comment: Which browser are you testing with?
What criteria are you using to see if the images are fully loaded?
In my code I'm using the width and height property to know that...but I wonder if there are other methods?